# Which hook to allow specific users to add/edit/view comments?

Tags: 7, comments

Is there a hook that I can use that would give specific users permissions to add a comment, or edit their own comment?  I was hoping there would be something like hook_node_access().

In my form, I have a select list with all the users that the submitter can choose.  If the person is selected, then that selected person can comment on that specific node.

I looked at the [comment access module](http://drupal.org/project/commentaccess), but that does not work since it is still being controlled by role permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no hook to do this. One possibility that doesn't require editing of the comment module is to change the comment status of the node depending on the current user using `hook_node_load`:

```
function MyModule_node_load($nodes, $types) {
    global $user;
    foreach($nodes as $node) {
        if(!user_has_access_to_node($user, $node)) {
            $node->comment = COMMENT_NODE_HIDDEN;
        }
    }
}
```

The hook will be called after the one in comment module, and will prevent users from posting comments unless `user_has_access_to_node` returns true.

The implementation of `user_has_access_to_node` would simply check if the current user is in the list of users allowed to edit the viewed node.

Comment: This is a good suggestion, however, it still requires me to give the specific user the allow comment permissions to leave a comment, which is something I want to avoid since I would then have to control comment permissions throughout my entire site.  But since you told me there is no hook to control comment access, then I will just write my own module that is very similar to the comments module, but with my own set of rules based on field values from the select dropdown list.